# Can I further simplify $\frac{-2\log 6}{\log 6-\log 4}$?

Tags: logarithms

Can I further simplify this logarithmic expression somehow in this case, or is it already the point when I take a calculator?

[image]

Comment: Well, you can rewrite it in terms of $\log 2$ and $\log 3$ if you prefer, but I'm not sure that's any simpler.

Comment: @lulu - "... you can rewrite it in terms of log2 and log3 if you prefer" - How could I do that?

Comment: $\log 6 = \log 2+\log 3$ and  $\log 4=2\log 2$.  Definitely worth trying but, as I say, I don't think the resulting expression is any simpler.

Comment: @lulu - Ah! I got it! Thank you.

Comment: $\log 6-\log 4=\log{6\over 4}=\log{3\over 2}$, ${\log 6 \over \log {3\over 2}}=\log_{3\over 2} 6$, $-2\log_a 6=\log_a 6^{-2}=\log_a {1\over 36}$, then answer is $\log_{3\over 2} {1\over 36}$, which is the same as $\log_{2\over 3} 36$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\log 6=\log (2\cdot 3) =\log2+\log3$, and $\log 4=2\log 2$. So x could be simplified to $\frac{-2\log 6}{\log \frac{3}{2}}$

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer an expression with ust one log-term in it, divide by $\log 6$:

$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{-2\log 6}{\log6 - \log4} \\
&= \frac{-2}{1-\log_6 4} \\
&= \frac{2}{\log_6 4 -1} \\
\end{align}$$

If you prefer log in the numerator, you can absorb $-1=\log_6 6$ into the other log term and use $\log_a b = 1/\log_b a$:

$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{2}{\log_6 4 -\log_6 6} \\
&= \frac{2}{\log_6 (4/6)} \\
&= 2 \log_{2/3} 6 = -2\log_{1.5} 6\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Interesting! Thank you.